# Generate 6 digit random number in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to generate random 6 digit number in mysql but sometime it generate only 5 digit.

`UPDATE member SET updates = FLOOR(RAND() * 999999)`

Comment: And what is wrong with your code?  Your question is rather ambiguous.

Comment: I update question.

Comment: select floor(rand()*900000)+100000;

Comment: Do you mean random unique 6 digit number?

Comment: Yes......  @RaghuAriga

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If the problem is that you are missing leading zeros, you can left pad with spaces:

```
UPDATE member
    SET updates = LPAD(FLOOR(RAND() * 999999.99), 6, '0');
```

I hope you understand that "random" means "random" and different rows can get the same value.

Comment: Just to mention, this creates a string and not an integer, float, double or some other type of number.

Comment: @gordon above some time generates the 5 digit number, how to force it to generate 6 digit code.

Comment: @ds9 . . . This generates a number between 0 and 999999, which is six digits.  Perhaps you have *another* question.  Perhaps your destination value is a *number* not a *string*.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks its turn out where i was storing otp was int and hence removed the leading zero.

Answer (score 2):

This generate 6 digit number exactly:

```
UPDATE member SET updates = FLOOR((RAND() * (999999-100000+1))+100000);
```

Comment: What is the point of `(999999-100000+1)`?

Comment: Max number with 6 digits, Min number with  6 digits

Comment: My question is why `999999-100000+1` and not `900000`

Comment: Just for being more didactic and can be applied to other cases

Comment: How could it be more *didactic* without an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate random 6 digit number in mysql

```
UPDATE member SET updates = LPAD(FLOOR(RAND() * 999999.99), 6, '0');
+--------+
| Value  |
+--------+
| 499540 |
| 550607 |
| 254419 |
| 620272 |
| 338104 |
| 829705 |
+--------+
```

or you can also random number generate in mysql 1 to 200 in increment form. you can change in place of 200 to **** as you like

```
UPDATE member SET updates = FLOOR(1 + (RAND() * 200));
    +--------+
    | Value  |
    +--------+
    | 1      |
    | 180    |
    | 50     |
    | 85     |
    | 33     |
    | 165    |
    +--------+
```